# Identical SQL query works on some tables but errors out on other tables same in the same DB

Tags: sql, sql-server, oracle, odbc, netsuite

I'm a finance person (little programming background) so I maybe asking something obvious for database programming experts but will appreciate any advice

Background:

I'm accessing Oracle NetSuite database via ODBC from Microsoft SQL Management Studio

Connection as a Linked Server is established successfully

I'm trying to execute the following SQL statements:

```
select * from [NETSUITE_SB2].[SB-B].[Administrator].[VARIANCE] -- success 

select * from [NETSUITE_SB2].[SB-B].[Administrator].[WTAX_JOB] -- "Msg 7314, Level 16, State 1, Line 1
The OLE DB provider "MSDASQL" for linked server "NETSUITE_SB2" does not contain the table ""SB-B"."Administrator"."WTAX_JOB"". The table either does not exist or the current user does not have permissions on that table."
```

Upon some testing, it appears that whether the query is successfully run depends on whether the table name contains "_" (underscore) - for all tables without underscore I've tried, it worked, for all tables with underscore that I've tried, it failed.

Can anyone help me figure out how to overcome this?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Suggestion: Familiarise yourself with the code formatting options available in the editor - thats impossible to read.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of using a 4-part name in SQL Server and having SQL Server generate a query for the linked server, try using the OPENQUERY function and passing a query in the target system's SQL dialect directly.  Something like:

```
select * 
from OPENQUERY([NETSUITE_SB2], 'select * from [SB-B].[Administrator].[WTAX_JOB]' )
```

Comment: Is this not a bug? I.e. a linked server query should generate a valid query

Comment: Definitely not a bug.  OP is using using MSDASQL, which is the OleDb Provider for ODBC.  When you do that SQL Server knows _exactly nothing_ about what the ODBC data source is or what kind of queries it supports.  The best it can do is guess.

Answer (score 0):

I just encountered this myself in a new instance that I just set up. I had been using Suite Connect for 4+ years without running into this issue before.

I believe the issue with the situation here is the "[SB-B]" part of the name because it contains the "-" dash. I found that a "," comma or "." period were the issue with my name [Acme, Inc.]. Ether the period or comma threw the error.

The second part of the 4-part name is the NetSuite [Company Name] under General Settings Company Info. I changed the name in NetSuite and removed the comma and period and the problem went away. Maybe most special characters cause the issue?

Just remember you'll have to update your second part name in each query you created before.

While using OPENQUERY is a solution, I just don't like the extra quotes needed so I prefer normal SQL.